# Why $C^{\infty}(M)$ module of sections of a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ is a reflexive module?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

As the title saying,

Why $C^{\infty}(M)$ module of sections of a vector bundle $E\rightarrow M$ is a reflexive module?

Here we are considering vector bundles with finite-dimensional fibers.

Comment: Surely this just boils down to the fact that it's true fibrewise?

Comment: I have no idea.. I'm new to this area and and everything is totally a mess to me now..maybe I will read more and think over it again..

Comment: Can you say something about the source of this fact?

Comment: That is true, since the global section is a finitely generated projective module.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the [Serre-Swan Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem), which states that modules of section are characterized as projective finitely generated $C^\infty(M)$-modules.

Hence for any vector bundle $E\to M$ the natural map $\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)^{\vee\vee}$ is

- injective, because $\Gamma(E)$ is finitely generated,
- surjective, because $\Gamma(E)$ is projective.

**Fun fact:** Any manifold $X$ admits a ﬁnite atlas consisting of $\dim X+1.$ (You can find this fact in the book below on page 5) Applying this to $X=E$ we have that $\Gamma(E)$ can be generated by $m+e+1$ elements where $m=\dim M$ and $e$ is the dimension of the fibers of $E.$

*Kolář, Ivan; Michor, Peter W.; Slovák, Jan*, [**Natural operations in differential geometry**](http://www.emis.de/monographs/KSM/), Berlin: Springer-Verlag. vi, 434 p. (corrected electronic version) (1993). [ZBL0782.53013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0782.53013).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in a comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808945/sections-of-the-dual-bundle-of-a-smooth-vector-bundle) question, we have $\Gamma(E)^\vee\cong\Gamma(E^\vee)$, and hence $\Gamma(E)^{\vee\vee}\cong\Gamma(E^{\vee\vee})\cong\Gamma(E)$.